# How to 'show' an application through another application (visual c++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cocos2d-x

I don't know if the title makes any sense to you guys and i'm not very good with English so i'll explain my problem through images (i don't have enough rep so sorry about that)

So in my solution I have 2 projects:

[image]

What i'm trying to do is to 'show' my second one through the first, like this:

[image]

I sound like a total noob... but is this possible? if it is, how can i achieve this?

Both are written in C++

Thank you for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31379495/4499919

Comment: oh I post the wrong image xD, no i don't mean runs an .exe file. Here's an example: https://github.com/fjz13/Cocos2d-x-ParticleEditor-for-Windows/tree/master/ParticleEditor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complicated question to answer completely in a reasonable amount of space. so I can provide first, the assurance that it has been done so is possible, and second, the broad outline of how to proceed.

There are basically two approaches that are possible depending on your desired level of integration:
Windows screensavers are standalone exe files. Despite this they can render themselves to the windows 'preview' dialog.
This is accomplished by the screensaver.exe being launched by the preview dialog - which passes its HWND on the command line.

So - to do this you would need to do 3 things

- Convince your managed app (CocosHelper) to give you an HWND for the form, and launch your cocos app with a command line containing that number.
- In your cocos project you would go to your AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching implementation, and retrieve the hwnd from the command line.
- You would create a subclass of the windows GLViewImpl class, which would - upon creating the OpenGL view, set its parent to the provided window - Your applicationDidFinishLaunching method would create this subclassed GLViewImpl rather than the base cocos version.

The next approach builds on this to put the cocos project into the same process space as the host app - assuming the host app is a win32 desktop app.

- Create a 3rd "CocosDllProject" as a clone of the "CocosProject" project. Change it to "Dynamic Library" rather than "Application" and remove the "main.cpp" file.
- Add a new "CocosDllMain.cpp" file and add an entrypoint function to it. "RunCocos" or something. Make sure this method is exported from the dll, and it will have the contents of the previous "main" method, but it should take, as a parameter, an HWND parameter that it will pass to (a modified) AppDelegate. This will be the parent window.
- Add this dll as a dependency to the other project, and invoke the "RunCocos" at the appropriate time.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explaination, upvoted. Your second aproach worked (haven't tried the first), but only for cocos2d-x 2.x, in 3.x they removed CCEGLView::SetParentHwnd() so there's no way around it without modifying the framework's source code itself, seems really risky to me so i'll stick with 2.x. Anyway for those who are interested here's the link (chinese): http://www.cnblogs.com/GuyaWeiren/p/4600937.html

Comment: You don't need to modify the framework source code. Create your own class that subclasses from CCEGLView.

Comment: You mean subclass GLViewImpl and override initWithRect() method? but  glfwCreateWindow doesn't allow me to specify parent windows though.

Comment: Oh and i was wrong about what i said erlier, looks like i actually used modified codes so there was a function  called SetParentHwnd(). i'll look more into it.

Comment: cocos 2.x didn't use glfw (yep I just figured out what what glfw is...) so that why I could easily set the parent windows...